# Can I paint over a stain on a laminated cabinet?

Tags: bathroom

I got a stain on my bathroom cabinet that won't come out.  It is a laminated wall cabinet.  Can I paint over this?

Answer (score 3):

Most any surface can be painted with the proper prep and paint. Before I can recommend the right product, can you answer these questions:

What kind of laminate do you have?  White foil, melamine, Formica, wood veneer?

What is it stained with?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a paint made for laminate counter tops you could check out.  I painted my son's dresser in a similar situation.  I sanded well and primed first; still looking good.  Like any paint job, I would assume the prep work is the key.